# OpenShift remote debugging on JBoss 7

Tags: jboss7.x, openshift, remote-debugging, portforwarding

I read over a couple of places that OpenShift allows remote debugging on JBoss 7 by using port forwarding. I am using a free OpenShift account with JBoss 7 to deploy a JSP application. After enabling JPDA marker, i'm not seeing the default debug port of 8787 listed under the list of ports to forward. Am I doing anything wrong here, or is it the case that remote debugging is no longer supported/not available in the free account ?

Reference: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Developer_Studio/7.1/html/User_Guide/Debug_a_Deployed_Application.html

Comment: Nice questioin I am looking at the moment for a answer ;) great pity it has not been answered :(